# Splice a 45W MagSafe 2 connector onto an 85W PSU?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, power, magsafe

I have an unused 45W MacBook Air MagSafe 2 PSU, and an 85W MagSafe 1 PSU that my dog chewed the connector off.

I'm wondering if splicing the MagSafe 2 connector onto the 85W PSU would allow a MacBook *Pro* to draw the full capacity from the 85W PSU, or would it limit itself to the nominal capacity identified by the MagSafe *connector*'s ID chip (i.e. that of the 45W PSU)?

Also, assuming it worked, would it be likely to cause any heat issues etc. - I'm assuming all MagSafe connectors would be electrically capable of handling the higher current, but is that a safe assumption?

Answer (score 1):

The price difference between Apple's 85W and 45W power adapters has always been very small, which one could assume means that they probably use the same high quality components (wiring and connector) for both, with the only difference being the size and output of the adapter. This also makes sense from a manufacturing perspective, but naturally we will never know for sure unless we get a statement from Apple about it (which, of course, we can assume we won't).

Considering the above, I certainly think what you're asking might be *possible* with the right amount of skill, but the question you need to ask yourself is **if it's worth saving a few bucks for a very likely fire hazard in your home** (or wherever you would use the adapter).

Comment: Well if it were a very likely fire hazard, then even at the €80 they cost here (which I personally consider more than just a few bucks), I still wouldn't risk it. But since it's at the DC side of the adapter and at these voltages and currents I'd have thought the worst that's likely to happen is the connector would melt and *maybe* the MacBook would be damaged by the heat... More interested in the first part of the question though (should probably have asked separately). Might try a controlled experiment myself with an ammeter (in a fireproof location :-) if no-one knows offhand.

Comment: @CupawnTae you're right in that it's more than "a few bucks" to buy a new  adapter from Apple or authorized resellers, but do have a look at places like [eBay's MagSafe category](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/magsafe-2) where it seems you can buy a new OEM MagSafe 2 power adapter for less than half the price of what Apple is charging.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. Of course, then you're trusting that they really are genuine/OEM adapters and not cheap knock-offs - because those really would be fire hazards. Worth thinking about though.